# Re-executing a query in LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can i prevent re-execute a query by refreshing a page in [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) framework?

Comment: Try to store the result in [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/cache)

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve it by Cache. You can use just has() and add() like this:

if(Cache::has('key')
{
return ...
}
else
{
Cache::add('key','value',time);
return ...
}